# 000webhost API returns net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api

I made an API with PHP, the problem is that when I tried to use `fetch` to retrieve data it doesn't work:

> OPTIONS http://my-app.000webhostapp.com/newapi/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

The thing is that when I try to make a request with Postman everything works fine any tips?

Example code from return:

```
public function throwError($code, $message) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");
            header("content-type: application/json; Charset='UTF-8'");
            header("cache-control: no-cache;");
            $errorMsg = json_encode(['error' => ['status'=>$code, 'message'=>$message]]);
            echo $errorMsg;
            exit();
        }
```

and I even get `net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR` if I try to call the API throw https

Sample call using fetch:

```
fetch("http://my-app.000webhostapp.com/newapi/", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "getAllSeriesByType",
        param: {
          type: serieType
        }
      })
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        }
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            series: responseData.response.result,
            loading: false
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          series: "There was an internal error retry later."
        });
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with 000webhosting they had some issues :( it took them 3 weeks to fix it.